# Samsung Storage Cloud API

Tags: api, cloud, storage, samsung-mobile-sdk

This might a be a broad question or a wrong place, but has anybody dealt with any api's from Samsung?

My interest is with Samsung Cloud api which would potential allow me to gain information on files which are stored on users account?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Samsung does not provide that opportunity to developers. On Samsung official website there is no information on Cloud APIs. Here is page for your reference

https://developer.samsung.com/build

Samsung Knox talks a little bit about Cloud but it is cloud authentication. Link is below

https://docs.samsungknox.com/dev/common/web-services.htm

Hope this will help.